# How to put a string variable inside a doublequote?

Tags: c#

So I would like to create a text(like a log file) from the database. Each text represent a user's record.
Obviously each record has different name according to the database.
And I am wondering how to put the string variable inside the doubleqoute when creating the text file.

```
public static void createLog()
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=s_project;UID=root;PASSWORD='';";SELECT

    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand thiscommand = con.CreateCommand();
    thiscommand.CommandText = "SELECT user_name FROM user_info";
    MySqlDataReader read = thiscommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        string user_name;
        user_name = read.GetString("user_name");

        StreamWriter SW;
        SW = File.CreateText("c:\\MyTextFile.txt"); //what should I put instead of MyTextFile if I would like it to be the variable user_name?
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use + (string concat) operator.

```
SW = File.CreateText("c:\\" + user_name + ".txt");
```

Comment: While AVD answer's is 100% correct, when dealing with string concatenation and file systems I recommend using `Path.Combine(...)`. `SW = File.CreateText(Path.Combine("C:\\", user_name, ".txt"));`

Comment: @NickBabcock, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`String.Format` also works if you start needing more variables:

```
SW = File.CreateText(String.Format("c:\\{0}.txt", user_name));
```

It can show intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use + symbol

```
SW = File.CreateText(@"C:\" + user_name + ".txt");
```